# How to convert Array of Map<String, Object> to Map<Long, Long> using streams

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, nullpointerexception, java-stream

```
public class Sample {

    Map<Long, Long> count(Map<String, UserStats> visits[]) {

        Map<Long, Long> visitsNum = new HashMap<>();
        Arrays.stream(visits).map(m -> {

            Map<Long, Long> visitsList = new HashMap<>();
            m.forEach((k, v) -> {
                String microSerNum = k;
                UserStats user = v;
                Long count1 = 0L;
                Long longMicroSerNum =0L;
                try {
                    longMicroSerNum = Long.parseLong(microSerNum);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("Microserive number is not a Long data type");
                    return;
                }
                if (user == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("User not visited the Microservice " + longMicroSerNum);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    Optional<Long> count = user.VisitCounter;

                    if (count.isPresent())

                    count1 = count.get();

                    System.out.println("Number of times user vistied the Microservice " +longMicroSerNum + " is "+ count1);

                }

                visitsList.put(longMicroSerNum, count1);

            });
            
            return visitsList;

        }).//collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey, e->e.getValue));
        
        forEach((e) -> {
            System.out.println(e);
        });


        return visitsNum; // should return a map
    }

    record UserStats(Optional<Long> VisitCounter) {

    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        Sample a = new Sample();
        UserStats u = new UserStats(Optional.of(10L));
        UserStats u1 = new UserStats(Optional.of(20L));

        Map<String, UserStats> m1[] = new HashMap[10];

        Map<String, UserStats> m2 = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, UserStats> m3 = new HashMap<>();
        m2.put("20", u);
        m2.put("30", u1);
        m3.put("", u);
        m3.put("50", null);

        m1[0] = m2;
        m1[1] = m3;

        Map<Long, Long> visitsNum = a.count(m1); //should catch the returned map
        
    }

}
```

Have to parse the String, Object's Optional values to Long types then discard the empty object or empty string values.

Getting below console output:

```
Number of times user vistied the Microservice 30 is 20
Number of times user vistied the Microservice 20 is 10
{20=10, 30=20}
Microserive number is not a Long data type
User not visited the Microservice 50
{}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)" because "m" is null
    at CodingPractice.Sample.lambda$0(Sample.java:12)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at CodingPractice.Sample.count(Sample.java:48)
    at CodingPractice.Sample.main(Sample.java:78)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, UserStats> m1[] = new HashMap[10];
```

and further:

```
m1[0] = m2;
m1[1] = m3;
```

Only two elements are in your array of length 10, others are then set to `null`. Then, what do you think it will happen in `count()` at the call `m.forEach` if `m` is null?

Change `Map<String, UserStats> m1[] = new HashMap[10];` to `Map<String, UserStats> m1[] = new HashMap[2];`

Aside: you are creating a generic array but that is bad (the compiler should have complain); your problem is mainly due to the fact that you used an array (fixed size and logical error then) where something like a list would have been much safer. Or at least filter the stream for non null elements...

Comment: Changed Array size to 2 instead of default 10 size to avoid Null pointer.

Comment: Filtered non empty Map values. Using generic Array is a bad idea but in my case input requirement is generic array to count method.

Comment: In **count** method, simply converting visits[] to ' visitsNum' then returning it. Any suggestion on how to collect 'visitsNum' as Map<Long, Long> instead of stream's 'forEach'?

Comment: @Jaya use stream collect method to convert Map<String,UserStats> to Map<Long,Long> then collect to count...

Comment: return value is a  stream of Map values so instead of collect method used reduce method as below  `reduce((firstMap, secondMap) -> {
     firstMap.putAll(secondMap);
     return firstMap;
    }).orElse(null); `

Answer (score -1):

```
package CodingPractice;

import java.util.*;

public class Sample {
   //converting array of map objects to simple map objects
    Map<Long, Long> mapArrayObjects(Map<String, UserStats> visits[]) 
{

     //converting array to list to perform stream operations
        List<Map<String, UserStats>> lMap = Arrays.asList(visits);

        Map<Long, Long> visitsNum = new HashMap<>();

        visitsNum = lMap.stream().map(m -> {

            Map<Long, Long> visitsList = new HashMap<>();

            m.entrySet().forEach((e) -> {
           /* UserStats contain a field count which is number of 
            times user visited a micro service */
                UserStats user = e.getValue();
                Long count = 0L;
               //micro service number
                Long longMicroSerNum = 0L;
                try {
                    longMicroSerNum = Long.parseLong(e.getKey());
                } catch (Exception e1) {

                    System.out.println("Microserive number is not a 
                     Long data type");
                    return;
                }
                if (user == null) {
                    System.out.println("User not visited the 
                 Microservice " + longMicroSerNum);
                    return;
                } else {
                //number of times visited a micro service
                    Optional<Long> NoVisited = user.VisitCounter;

                //retrieving count value from a UserStats object
                    if (NoVisited.isPresent())
                        count = NoVisited.get();

                    System.out.println(
                            "Number of times user vistied the 
                 Microservice " + longMicroSerNum + " is " + count);
                    visitsList.put(longMicroSerNum, count);

                /* we could also set values directly to 
                  visitsNum to avoid reduce() logic on visitsList */
                    // visitsNum.put(longMicroSerNum, count);

                }

            });

            return visitsList;

        }).filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())

                .peek(System.out::println)

                .reduce((firstMap, secondMap) -> {
                    firstMap.putAll(secondMap);
                    return firstMap;
                }).orElse(null);

        return visitsNum;
    }

    record UserStats(Optional<Long> VisitCounter) {

    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        UserStats u = new UserStats(Optional.of(10L));
        UserStats u1 = new UserStats(Optional.of(20L));

        Map<String, UserStats> m1[] = new HashMap[3];

        Map<String, UserStats> m2 = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, UserStats> m3 = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, UserStats> m4 = new HashMap<>();
        //setting test data with non empty values
        m2.put("20", u);
        m2.put("30", u);
       //setting test data with empty key and null value
        m3.put("", u);
        m3.put("50", null);
       //again setting data with non empty values
        m4.put("60", u1);
        m4.put("70", u1);

        m1[0] = m2;
        m1[1] = m3;
        m1[2] = m4;

        Map<Long, Long> visitsNum = sample.mapArrayObjects(m1);
        visitsNum.forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println("Key is " + k + " " + "value is " + 
            v);
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added comments for better understanding, hope this makes my answer clear.

Comment: Please read the [answer] link. You want to add more than comments. Rather, add a paragraph or two or three of non-code related text, text that fully explains the problem that your answer solves and how your answer solves it. This is all to help the question and answer both be helpful to future visitors who come to the site looking for solutions to similar problems.